# Poner una imagen en un picturebox con código | Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Quiero saber ¿Cómo puedo hacer para poner una imagen en un picturebox en visual Studio, por código? tengo las imágenes en la carpeta Resources (archivo de recursos), y quiero saber como llamar a esa imagen por código en el picture box.

**Lo único que tengo es esto:**

```
PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("../../Resources/verde.png")
```

*Pero no me sirve cuando intento usar el programa en una computadora distinta.*

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Esa ruta, es en tu computadora... estas mandando el archivo con tu programa? entonces, en que ruta lo estas mandando? y llegado el cado, si va como recurso interno, deberias leerlo de ahi....

Comment: @gbianchi lo quiero usar como recurso interno, pero no se como ponerlo por código

Comment: en tu programa esta como static resource?

Comment: @gbianchi esta por defecto, como lo crea Visual

Comment: visual no lo crea de ninguna forma... esta en vos como lo agregaste al proyecto.. y depende como lo agregaste al proyecto es la forma de leerlo... agrega a tu pregunta de que forma lo agregaste al proyecto y como lo estas mandando...

Comment: @gbianchi "Resources" es una carpeta que ahí tengo las imagenes

Comment: Perfecto.. y esa carpeta la estas mandando en tu instalacion? la estas copiando a la salida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me imagino que te refieres al archivo de recursos, que se visualiza como una carpeta en Visual Studio.

Para tomar una imagen importada en "Resources" debes hacer referencia a su nombre (asignado o bien el nombre del archivo sin la extensión)

```
Dim bmp as System.Drawing.Bitmap = My.Resources.NombreImagen
PictureBox2.Image = bmp
```

Comment: Me sale un error en "Properties" dice que no es un miembro de mi proyecto

Comment: @LeNdroX, Prueba con `My.Resources.NombreImagen`

Comment: ahora si me funciona, gracias perdone la molestia